# microsoft SQL - returning previous week's data

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that I refresh every week to get the sales data of the last week with the duration starting from last week's Sunday and ending with last week's Saturday. For example if I am running the script in any day within the week from 09/18/16 to 09/24/16, I want to get the sales data spanning from 09.11.16 to 09.17.16.

What script/syntax can I use to get this data if I want to refresh in any day of the current week to get the previous week's data?

Appreciate your time,

Thanks!

Comment: It worked thru Hadi's advice - when I put the statement in this way:                                   Where [Sales Date]  between dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, @date)-1), @date)) and  dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, 7-(datepart(dw, @date)), @date))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
declare @date date = getdate()
select dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, @date)-1), @date)) as [Start],
       dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, 7-(datepart(dw, @date)), @date)) as [End]
```

Here a working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db5/522)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you so much Hadi. I tried - it works however it is giving me much more rows than if I manually specify the timing. Mt script is very long, it also has group by, do i need to add the exact same statement in group by?  Or maybe I should not put in this statement in select but after where clause?                                                                                               Also there is a column for capturing the dates called "sales date" - if i want to specify through this column the timeframe - should i just write  - where "sales date" and this statement?

Comment: It worked when i wrote this way: Where [Sales Date] between dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, @date)-1), @date)) and dateadd(wk,-1,dateadd(dd, 7-(datepart(dw, @date)), @date)